# digital ocean redirect non-www to www

Tags: nginx, redirect, digital-ocean

I'm trying to redirect my domain `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com` on Digital Ocean.

I have A records for both www and @, so the site is accessible at each domain, but the redirect is not working. Here is what I have in my default config file (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default):

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /var/www/app/deploy/frontend/;
index index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name example.com;

location / {
# First attempt to serve request as file, then
# as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
# Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
# include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}
}

#Redirect example.com to www.example.com

server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
return 301 http://www.example.com.io$request_uri;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to define them in separate server blocks. Can be within the same file though like this:

```
server {
    server_name  domain.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    server_name  www.domain.com;
    #The rest of your configuration goes here#
}
```

Comment: working now. thanks Adam. I would +1 if I had enough reputation

Comment: No worries, you can mark as answered though by clicking the tick to mark the question answered

Comment: Not working on my https site, getting "Bad Request (400)" with no error log in nginx

Answer (score -3):

Create a CNAME record with 'yoursite.com' is an alias of '@'[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. The CNAME record becomes `yoursite.com.yoursite.com` is an alias of `yoursite.com`